# Calculating duplicate permutations in Python

Tags: python, permutation

Say I have this list :
    [1,1,2,2]
I want to run through all the permutations of this.
If I print the same permutation will be printed 4 times.
For [1,1,1,3] the same one will be printed 6 times,
For [1,1,1,3,3] 12.

In General : (a1)!*(a2)!*...(an)!
Is there any function that does that in Python?
If no, can you give me an algorithm that does in Python?

Comment: You included the algorithm in your question. Your formula defines an algorithm.

Comment: Okay I know mathematics but I don't really know how to imply this knowledge to python

Comment: have you tried searching Google for factorial in python? then multiplying results in python? i think it does not require top coder level python experience.

Comment: A basic "python permutation" search leads you here from where you can identify the duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: Well I need to know the amount of duplicates of every item in the list without counting the same thing twice..

Comment: runDOSrun - I want to find a number, not to generate permutations.

Comment: You don't need to find out the number of duplicates algorithmically, it's mathematically well-defined: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algebra/apr2/LpermRep.htm

Comment: How do I know in python how many duplicates of each item I have ?

Comment: `len(mylist)-len(set(mylist))` or just loop manually if you want to track it for every single item

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
import math

def repeats(nums):
    counts = dict()
    result = 1

    for n in nums:
        if n in counts:
            counts[n] += 1
        else:
            counts[n] = 1

    for n in counts.keys():
        result *= math.factorial(counts[n])

    return result

print repeats([1, 1, 2, 2])     # prints 4
print repeats([1, 1, 1, 3])     # prints 6
print repeats([1, 1, 1, 3, 3])  # prints 12
```